# Wildcard SSL Subdomain forwarding

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have an issue with my website. I have a web service that when users create an account they get their own subdomain (for example: john.example.com)

Everything works perfectly as expected, I have a wildcard SSL certificate which works fine when going to:

https://john.example.com/

BUT

If a user enters www.john.example.com Chrome stops the connection to the site and shows an SSL Error stating:

> Cannot connect to the real www.john.example.com
>
> Something is currently interfering with your secure connection to
>   www.john.example.com.
>
> Try to reload this page in a few minutes or after switching to a new
>   network. If you have recently connected to a new Wi-Fi network, finish
>   logging in before reloading.
>
> If you were to visit www.john.example.com right now, you might share
>   private information with an attacker. To protect your privacy, Chrome
>   will not load the page until it can establish a secure connection to
>   the real www.john.example.com.

This only happens in chrome. If I go to the URL www.john.example.com in Firefox or IE the connection completes and the htaccess forwards the user to https://john.example.com, but Chrome isn't giving the server a chance.

How do I fix this for the users?

Will i Have to buy another wildcard SSL cert for www.*.example.com ?

Comment: FYI: I've changed your example to use `example.com` as an example domain name. `mysite.com` is a real (and unrelated) domain used by a hosting company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an inherent limitation of wildcard SSL certificates — a wildcard component like the `*` in `*.example.com` can only replace a single hostname component (like `john`), not multiple levels (like `www.john`). You will need to structure your site such that it does not link to these subdomains with a `www`; or, if it must, that it does so without HTTPS.

It will most likely not be possible for you to obtain a wildcard certificate that is valid for these subdomains. SSL CAs are rarely willing to sign unusual wildcard certificates like the one you're considering (`www.*.example.com`).

Comment: Well linking isn't the issue, the site is setup to link to all subdomains correctly. The issue comes when a user inputs the url in the web browser bar, a lot of internet users still use "www." -  I was hoping there is a way for my site to redirect before Chrome throws the SSL Error

Comment: Surely, though, if a user typed in the URL it probably wouldn't have an "https" on it?

Comment: @theprestig3 Of course you can redirect the user via mod-rewrite or other means, but your post doesn't contain any questions on this. You need to edit and narrow down your question to something specific and programming-related (StackOverflow is about programming and not server management).

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Well there is a redirect already in place, my issue is with Chrome throwing the SSL error before the server can do anything. Essentially making the site inaccessible. My question is to find out if there is a way around the Google error since this only occurs on Chrome.

Comment: Ok this helped, I had to re-read your answer twice to fully understand the last bit. After some experimenting I saw that my redirect was automatically adding https, so if a user typed www they would get `https://www` -- the solution was to remove the www  from the url, then redirect which worked -- Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> Will i Have to buy another wildcard SSL cert for www.*.example.com ?

Even if you would be able to buy such a certificate  browser would not accept it.
Wildcard is only allowed in the leftmost label, see RFC6125 section 6.4.3. This means, no `www.*.example.com`, no `*.*.example.com` but only `*.site.example.com`.